# What are the good concurrency libaries in C++?

Tags: c++, concurrency

I am using [Intel's threading building block](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/%20Intel's%20Threading%20building%20block%20library)  library and it seems pretty good. But because of some licensing concerns, I may not be using it. So, what are other good C++ concurrency libraries?

Comment: c++ 11 has std::thread lib

Comment: Yes. C++11 has atomic, asynchronous task, condition variables, mutexes also. But it doesn't have concurrent queue, map etc.

Comment: You can implement those data structures by yourself?

Comment: in case you didn't notice, its GPL license is "with run-time exception". If you link dynamically and don't modify it, it is supposed to be fine, no GPL "contamination". Anyway, there is commercial license available too

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the operating system, platform and compiler that you need to support.

Compilers compliant with the C++11 standard already have concurrency support.

Other options are the **Boost** or **Qt** libraries.

Another option, for simple multithreading, is  **OpenMP**.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Boost::Concurrent](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/?view=category_Concurrent).  Looks like you're after [Boost::Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) which has queues *etc*.